# Problem with special characters Postgres + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, encoding, character

I've a e-mail configuration table containing the html content that will be sent. In this html content, there is many special character, but when I retrieve this content using hibernate, this characters are replaced for "?".

Any ideia about this problem?

PS: The database encode is "SQL_ASCII".

Thanks,
Rafael.

Answer (score 1):

I think you gave the answer yourself. Try setting the database encoding to UTF-8.

If that is not possible, encode the data with base64.